# Create User & Access Rules Github for Windows

Tags: git, version-control, github, git-svn

I've just installed Git using http://windows.github.com/

It seems to be installed correctly but I'm unable to create new users and access control setup to access repository. I have tried to look into the docs, but doesn't contains anything like that. I'm not sure whether Github for windows have these or not.

What do you suggest to use to solve this kind of situation.. I need to setup Git with user management & at least very basic access control on repository), is it possible with Git or not?

I'm fine with command prompt management console. Pls advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[GitHub for Windows](http://windows.github.com/) is a GitHub client for Windows, it's not a Git installer for Windows.

You installed a client that helps you to manage, commit, push and pull from and to your GitHub hosted Git repositories.

If you want to install Git on your machine go to [git-scm](http://git-scm.com/). If you want to install a git repository hosting, things are getting a little bit more complex, given that you want to do that on Windows. I don't think there is any existing project designed to run on Windows.

If you can use different OS, then [Gitolite](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/) is one of the most famous projects.

If you prefer hosted solutions, there are several alternatives such as [GitHub](http://github.com), [BitBucket](http://bitbucket.com), [CodeBase](http://www.codebasehq.com/) and many more.

Comment: What git repository hosting stack do you recommend? Is there any server for hosting Git with user management?

Comment: Thanks, I ended using a Gitblit for my need. Thanks again.