# URL for accessing Remote Git Repository

Tags: git, version-control

I've just installed Git using http://windows.github.com/ on our server.

It seems to be installed correctly. I want to know whether I can access the server's Git by some url? Although the one I installed doesn't give me any URL, it has just created a folder for repository nothing else.

I want to access this from other PC in network. Do I need to install Git on client system as well? How does it work?

Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GitHub for Windows is a client to access GitHub repositories, not a server. There a several applications available, which act as a server, like Gerrit, GitBlit etc. which should also work an Windows, since they are Java based (for GitBlit i'm sure, since i've used it on Windows). They also provide user management etc.

However, you can also just use a Windows Share to access the repositories on your server, but i wouldn't recommend that, if you have multiple users or if you want to apply access restrictions on the repository.

Of course you also have to install Git in your client systems. Depending on your needs and OSs etc. there are a command line client available (http://msysgit.github.com/) or some Gui clients like GitExtensions or SmartGit (commercial).

Comment: I ended up using GitBlit, and able to get it started within 15 minutes. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Same as [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12706719/create-user-access-rules-github-for-windows/).

[GitHub for Windows](http://windows.github.com/) is a GitHub client for Windows, it's not a Git installer for Windows.

You installed a client that helps you to manage, commit, push and pull from and to your GitHub hosted Git repositories.

If you want to install Git on your machine go to [git-scm](http://git-scm.com/). If you want to install a git repository hosting, things are getting a little bit more complex, given that you want to do that on Windows. I don't think there is any existing project designed to run on Windows.

If you can use different OS, then [Gitolite](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/) is one of the most famous projects.

If you prefer hosted solutions, there are several alternatives such as [GitHub](http://github.com), [BitBucket](http://bitbucket.com), [CodeBase](http://www.codebasehq.com/) and many more.

Comment: I can go for a Linux VM, CentOS or Ubuntu... Where should I look for help to install git repository hosting?

Comment: I updated my answer with the link to http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/

Comment: thank you, I'm looking into that now.

Comment: More updates for hosted vs local solutions.